# save a mailmerge document

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop, mailmerge

I need to produce and save a MS Word .doc file starting from a template (let's say C:\template.doc) and a datasource (let'say C:\datasource.doc)
I'm using MailMerge.Execute and if I let Word to be visible, I see the correct result file, but I can't realize to save this file in any way. The code is:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application myWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Object oFalse = false; Object oTrue = true; Object oFileName = @"C:\merged.doc";
Word.Document myMailMergeDoc = myWord.Documents.Open(@"C:\template.doc");
myMailMergeDoc.MailMerge.OpenDataSource(Name: @"C:\datasource.doc");
myMailMergeDoc.MailMerge.Destination = Word.WdMailMergeDestination.wdSendToNewDocument;
myMailMergeDoc.MailMerge.Execute(oFalse);
try
   { 
       myWord.Documents["template.doc"].Close(oFalse);
       myWord.Documents.Save(oFileName);
       myMailMergeDoc.SaveAs(oFileName);
       myWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(oFileName);
   }
catch(System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ex)
        { }
```

None of the three saving methods in the try block saves the file on the disk. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is assigned to oFileName? Try removing lines 2 & 3 in the try-block - I would not expect them to work. Line 4 should work... If it doesn't set: myWord.Visible = true; so that you can see the result of the mail merge execution. Are you able to save the result document (assuming it's there) to the oFileName path as an end-user?

Comment: Thanks Cindy, oFileName is set to @"C:\merged.doc";lines 2,3 and 4 are alternative, all of them don't work; yes, I'm able to save the document as end-user

Comment: Mmm, the next trouble-shooting steps I'd try would be: check how many documents are open in the Word instance. And try using myWord.Documents[indexValue].SaveAs - maybe Word doesn't think the document is Active...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did it: I missed to install VBA features from Office setup, now the document is correctly saved